# Parameterized PDO statements: should trusted, constant values be parameterized?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, parameterized-query

```
SELECT name FROM customers WHERE location = ? AND active = '1'
```

In this query, the value for *location* would come from an untrusted source, but the value for *active* is going to always be = 1. I'm using PDO for php/mysql.

**Should I also parameterize the value for *active*?**
 
**If *active* wasn't a constant but came from a changing and trusted source, should I still parameterize?** (ie. for caching benefits?)

Comment: The rule is: whenever you mix user data with the query, use parametrized query

Comment: an opinion based in code readability/comprehension: if its *constant*, hardcode it in the sql. Giving it the flexibility to vary makes the reader of your code wonder why/where you vary the value. But when hardcoded, at a glance someone can say "ah, this query gets all active users"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no benefit to parameterizing constant values.

The purpose of parameterizing is to allow application data to be combined with SQL expressions **safely** and **repeatedly**.  The safely part is to prevent SQL injection.  The repeatedly part is so you can execute a prepared query again with different values, possibly relieving the RDBMS from having to re-parse and re-optimize the query.

Neither of these is an issue if you always use the same constant value in your query.  You are not at risk of SQL injection from a hardcoded value, and you can re-execute the query if you need to, without re-parsing.

There's no caching of parameters going on.  If anything, using prepared statements makes it *harder* for MySQL to cache the results (i.e. the [query cache has limitation on caching results from prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-operation.html)).  But once you use prepared statements, it doesn't matter if it has one parameter versus two or more.

---

I do wonder why you put the integer in quotes.  I see that a lot, but I have no idea how that got started or who thought it was necessary.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Is it because they are not typically changing like those other values that are being manipulated by search filters/etc, so therefore not any caching benefit? Or is it because there simply is no security threat? Is it just a matter of security, that we parameterize?

Comment: I guess the 1 being in quotes is so I don't have to worry about if the database type is integer or not. Although that's a weak argument. Hah! I think part of the habit comes from doing this a lot in the past: `something = '".mysql_real_escape_string($untrusted)."'` and being super careful to have those quotes surrounding everything.

Comment: Thanks Bill! One more piece of clarity, you are saying that if it was not constant, but still trusted, then go ahead and parameterize it?

Comment: Yes, I like to parameterize all application variables if possible, just so the code is consistent.  I don't like to see any variables directly in SQL strings (though we can't parameterize some things like table names, column names, SQL expressions, keywords).